# Spring + Hibernate How to use AspectJ to control transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional.
So I want to use AspectJ, but I can not get session by `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, which leads to following Exception.
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

I have added VM arguments at runtime.
-javaagent:/Users/xx/workStation/workspace/SpringHibernate/src/lib/spring-instrument-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar

Here is configuration file
aop.xml

```
<aspectj>
<weaver options="-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true -showWeaveInfo">
</weaver>
```

beans.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref = "dataSource"/>
     <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>config/User.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
     </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.format_sql=false
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory"/>
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value = "true"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="txManager" />
<context:load-time-weaver />
```

Thank you for your answers. 
If I removed aop.xml I got a warning:
`warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified`. 
else I got following info 
`[AppClassLoader@546b97fd] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(java.util.List com.yonghui.sh.service.impl.UserServiceBean.getUsers())' in Type 'com.yonghui.sh.service.impl.UserServiceBean' (UserServiceBean.java:106) advised by around advice from 'org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect' (AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
[AppClassLoader@546b97fd] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.yonghui.sh.service.txtest.TxTestB.txC())' in Type 'com.yonghui.sh.service.txtest.TxTestB' (TxTestB.java:32) advised by around advice from 'org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect' (AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)`
. 
I think classes are weaved. I just use JUnit to run some tests not in web context.

It seems that the problem is "static".

```
static UserService userService;
static TxTest txTest;
static TxTestX txTestx;
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
    userService = (UserService)ac.getBean("UserService");
    txTest = (TxTest)ac.getBean("txTestA");
    txTestx = (TxTestX)ac.getBean("txTestX");
}
```

If I don't use JUnit it works well.

```
public class TxTestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
    TxTest txTestA = (TxTest)ac.getBean("txTestA");
    txTestA.txA();
}
```

}

How comes??

Comment: Try with removing the `aop.xml` and make sure that you have `spring-aspects.jar` in your classpath. Also make sure that you enable loadtimeweaving in the ContextLoaderListener(s) application context, else you might run into a situation where classes are already loaded and as such not weaved anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional.

I dont know if it is a problem here But a bean can invoke its own method through proxy. Just implement in your bean interfaces like ApplicationContextAware and BeanNameAware and having this two you can ask the context about the bean where you actually are and cal any method through proxy (in transaction). This of course work only when the scope is SINGLETON if it is PROTOTYPE there are also some ways to do that through API.